# Unexpected Node.js Behavior when using fsPromises.open

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

I have a larger app that is erroring out during this file writing operation. I'm trying to use fsPromises to create an autosave file, but the path variable I'm passing in appears to be losing it's value in between a debugging console log and the actual  call to open the file. It's very odd.

here's the code:

```
    static async writeFile(filepath, data) {
        try {
            console.log(4, filepath, typeof filepath);
            console.log(5, path.resolve(filepath))
            const fileHandle = await fs.open(filepath, 'w+');
            console.log(6, fileHandle)
            await fileHandle.truncate();
            await fileHandle.writeFile(data, 'utf8');
            await fileHandle.close();
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Error writing file: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
```

here's the relevant output (I've removed the directory structure, but I check it 5 times each time I run the script, and the output is optimized to find differences in strings easily, so I'm 99.99% sure the directory of the file location is correct)

```
4 C:\__dirname\savefile-autosave-2023-10-21T00:06:11.306Z.json string
5 C:\__dirname\savefile-autosave-2023-10-21T00:06:11.306Z.json
Error saving auto-save file: Error saving save file: Error writing file: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\__dirname\savefile-autosave-2023-10-21T00:06:11.306Z.json'
Error: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
```

to my knowledge, calling fsPromises (lazily called fs here, but it's defined as `const fs = require('fs').promises` at the top of the file) with the w+ flag should open the file even if it doesn't exist. But the error appears to be with something before that flag becomes relevant. I don't understand how console logs 4 and 5 are reading out the correct information, but the open function appears is some how getting undefined, even though the console logs are showing the variable as being defined. I'm not even sure what more I can do to debug this at this point. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I forgot some important information: I'm on windows using node version 18.18.2

Comment: I don't think you can have `:` in a filename for a start

Comment: @JaromandaX certainly not under Windows :-)

Comment: @traktor - the `C:` at the beginning would suggest this is a Windows environment too ... also, even in windows, don't you use `/` as a path separator in node? I do :p

Comment: @JaromandaX for general readership Windows has supported both back and forward slash path separators for some time. While I use '/' by default myself, under Windows, some `path` object methods in Node (`path.resolve` IIRC) put backslash separators in their return values anyway.

Comment: that's what `__dirname` is using for the resource paths, i mostly use the path module to create directories on this project. This is a typical way I create paths that would get fed into the open function: `path.join(__dirname, 'lastDirectoryInPath', 'savefile-autosave-' + new Date().toISOString() + '.json');`

after seeing that, does it look like the wrong way to do it?


the very weird thing is that it seems to switch from having a string value over to being undefined in between the console log and the open call, and i'm getting stuck on why/how that could happen.

Comment: ah dang it, i see the other :'s in the file path now, that's probably causing the issue. --- yep, that's absolutely what this issue was all about. taking the :'s out of the isoString filestamp uncovers another issue but satisfies this query. Thank you very much! if you submit that as an answer, i will accept it!

Comment: Do you really have a top-level directory named `__dirname` on your hard drive or is that supposed to be a string substitution in `C:\__dirname\savefile-autosave-2023-10-21T00:06:11.306Z.json` that isn't working properly?

Comment: that is a substitution lol i attempted to allude to it being just a substitution in the body of the post, but that's a fair question, i am quite wordy and sometimes am not clear because of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @JaromandaX's comment, the `:` character in the ISOString result is causing the issue because it's an invalid character in the Windows directory naming style